# Question regarding xmlns

Tags: xml, xpath

have an xml data like

```
<Item xmlns="http://www.sample.com">
<name>robert</name> ....
</Item>
```

want to know what is the default namespace here? Why we need an namespace here?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <Item xmlns="http://www.sample.com">
>   <name>robert</name> .... 
> </Item>
> ```
>
> want to know what is the default
>   namespace here?

The default namespace is "http://www.sample.com". Whenever a namespace is defined without a prefix, this is a definition of a default namespace for the current elementand all of its descendents, unless somewhere in the subtree topped by the current element there isn't a new default namespace defined (in this case it will shadow the previously defined default namespace for the subtree on which the new default namespace definition was done).

> Why we need an namespace here?

The main and only purpose of a namespace is to help distinguish identical names used in different subject areas.

For example: "item" of a sequence or "item" in an invoice; "book" to read or "book" a hotel.

Namespaces are necessary in any case when elements from two different XML documents covering different subject matters, must be combined into one single XML document -- booking a hotel and asking what books are in the hotel library may be an example.